# JAVA - Finding the distance between two sets of latitude and longitude

Tags: java

Below is the info I was given for this problem.
"According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distanceLinks to an external site., the great circle distance based on two coordinates in nautical miles is given by `Distance = Radius * DeltaAngle.`

The radius of the earth is a constant and its value in radians is `r = 10800 / PI.`

Given 2 coordinates (Lat1, Long1, Lat2, and Long2) the formula can be re-written as:

`DeltaAngle = acos(sin(Lat1) * sin(Lat2) + cos(Lat1) * cos(Lat2) * cos(Long1 – Long2))`

Because the coordinates on earth are given in degrees, you need to convert the degrees into radians by multiplying the `degrees * PI / 180`.

Create a static method called calcDistance and it should take two sets of coordinates (LatOrigin, LongOrigin, LatDestin, and LongDestin) and it should return the distance in nautical miles using the formula above. Keep in mind the Greek symbols are not allowed in java.

In the main method, you will ask the user to enter two coordinates (LatOrigin, LongOrigin, LatDestin, LongDestin) and you will calculate the distance in nautical miles using the method above.

Then you will display to the user the correspondent distance rounded to one decimal (i.e. 105.5 NM). Then, also display the distance in statute miles. This is the distance in nautical `miles * 1.15`."

I feel like I have the equation correct but I'm entering San Diego latitude `32.7335556` longitude `-117.1896667` and New York latitude `40.6397511` longitude `-73.7789256` and the distance is coming out much lower than it should.

```
public class Airport {
public static double calcDistance(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
double radius = 10800/Math.PI;// formula given in instructions
double distance, deltaAngle;

deltaAngle = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(long1-long2)); //Delta Angle formula given in instructions
deltaAngle = deltaAngle * Math.PI/180; //converts Earth radius to radians.
distance = radius * deltaAngle;
return distance;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double lat1, long1, lat2, long2, distanceNautical, distanceStatute;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Please enter latitude of origin point: ");
    lat1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter longitude of origin point: ");
    long1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.print("Please enter latitude of destination point: ");
    lat2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter longitude of destination point: ");
    long2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.close();
    
    distanceNautical = calcDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2); //distance in Nautical Miles.
    distanceStatute = distanceNautical * 1.15; //distance in standard miles.
    
    //output in nautical and statute miles
    System.out.printf("Distance in Nautical Miles = %.1f\n", distanceNautical);
    System.out.printf("Distance in Statute Miles = %.1f\n", distanceStatute);
    // My distances come out low, I've tried playing with the equation but I'm not sure what is wrong, looks like it matches what we were give to use. 
}
}
```

Comment: The Java trig functions use radians.

Comment: Thanks. I commented out the conversion of deltaAngle to radians and got 5445.3 nautical and 6262 miles which closer but is too large now. So I'm still off on something somewhere, or the equation given is off.

Comment: The Java trig functions, such as `Math.sin()`, take values in radians as parameters. So if you enter a value in degrees, like `32.7335556`, you need to convert it to radians *before* you pass it to a trig function.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's gotten me close now. 3215.8 nautical, 3698.2 miles.
EDIT: Nevermind I found and error and is coming out correct now. Thank you so much!

Comment: _"The radius of the earth is a constant and its value in radians is ..."_  - umm what?  You shouldn't measure distances in radians.  Ever.

Comment: @PeterGodoy Glad you solved your problem. Now you can draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.